# How refresh margin left on windows resize

Tags: jquery

I need dynamically change image margin on windows resize. But when I resize the window I need to refresh the page so I get the image in the right place. Is there a way wothout refreshing the page to get the right margin.

```
var iw = $(window).width();
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {    


            updateContainer();
            $(window).resize(function() {
                updateContainer();
            });


        });     

        function updateContainer(){

            $( ".rimg" ).each(function() {                  
                var w =$(this).width();             
                if(w>iw){                       
                    marg = (w-iw);

                    $($(this)).css("margin-left", function() { return "-"+marg+"px" });
                }


            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following script

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {    
       $(window).resize(function() {
           var iw = $(window).width();
            updateContainer(iw);
        });


    });     

    function updateContainer(iw){

        $( ".rimg" ).each(function() {                  
            var w =$(this).width();             
            if(w>iw){                       
                marg = (w-iw);

                $($(this)).css("margin-left", function() { return "-"+marg+"px" });
            }


        });
    }
```

You have declared the `iw` outside the resize function so it will give the same window size only, try with declaring the window size inside the `resize` function